# Simple Harmonic Motion of square/rectangular lamina and discs/rings about an axis parallel to the plane of object passing through centre of it

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, torque

[image][image]

I can't understand why if we tilt any describe object above(say given in picture about x/y axis) we observe Simple Harmonic Motion (SHM) of that body about it. It should not possible as, when we tilt it slightly we see that net torque provided by centre of mass of the two halves of the body is zero and there is no restoring torque.
Please explain that is it friction force that is applied in real life, if yes then please explain in detail?

Comment: Hi, I think your question is hard to understand. Can you add a bit of context? What do you mean by the acronym SHM?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Related:  [Why isn't this rod in neutral equilibrium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/648679/)

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, if the axis of rotation passes through the center of gravity of a physical pendulum, there will be no torque from gravity and no oscillation. So, what is the question?

Comment: Do this in real life you will see it goes oscillating