# Can someone please elaborate an answer about torque?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, torque, statistics

[Please explain Michael Seifert's answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/648679/)

- I think $x,y$ are distances but what is $d$?
- How did he get this formula?

x
  cos
  ⁡
  θ
  +
  d
  sin
  ⁡
  θ

- Does this equation implies Mgxcosθ= mgycosθ?

τ
  =
  −
  M
  g
  (
  x
  cos
  ⁡
  θ
  +
  d
  sin
  ⁡
  θ
  )
  +
  m
  g
  (
  y
  cos
  ⁡
  θ
  −
  d
  sin
  ⁡
  θ
  )
  =
  −
  (
  M
  +
  m
  )
  g
  d
  sin
  ⁡
  θ

- What does negative torque and positive θ displacement mean?

Any help would be wholeheartedly appreciated.

Comment: $x,y$ are horizontal distances. $d$ is the vertical height of the rod. Look at the diagram, he drew it in.

Comment: @Ghoster Fixed.

Comment: I also mention in that answer that "positive rotations are clockwise."  Similarly, counterclockwise torques and angular displacements are treated as negative.

Answer (score 0):

$d$ is the vertical thickness of the beam. The answer is pointing out that although an ideal one-dimensional beam (with $d=0$) will be in neutral equilibrium, a real beam (with $d>0$) will actually be in stable equilibrium. This is because if a beam with non-zero thickness is displaced by a small angle $\theta$ from the horizontal, the resulting torque $\tau = - (M+m)gd \sin \theta$ will be in the opposite direction to $\theta$ and so acts as a restoring torque.